# Jolt to change value based on another field

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to mask few fields based on `"Masking_col"` from the input.

Below is the expected input:

```json
{
  "IN_num": "1",
  "In_Details": "notworking",
  "customer_name": "abc",
  "customer_location": "Hyd",
  "customer_ID": "1001",
  "customer_name0": "abc",
  "Masking_col": "customer_location,customer_ID"
}
```

Here "Masking_col" contains "customer_location,customer_ID" these two field name, so in the output these two filed will be set to blank. Expected output will be:

```json
{
  "IN_num": "1",
  "In_Details": "notworking",
  "customer_name": "abc",
  "customer_location": "",
  "customer_ID": "",
  "customer_name0": "abc",
  "Masking_col": "customer_location,customer_ID"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with a ***split*** function within a **modify** transformation in order to get individual values to be evaluted lately as attribute names ( eg. `"customer_location"` and `"customer_ID"` ). Then combine their values as arrays which will have null values as the last components those will be converted to blank values within the last transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "MCol": "=split(',',@(1,Masking_col))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "MCol": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=lastElement",
      "customer_location|customer_ID": ["=isNull", ""]
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Barbaros, It worked like champ!